# Macro: Insert a new row above a cell containing a different numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, code

I have an excel with two columns. Column A contains numbers and column B contains text data. Numbers are continuous like 1 2 3 with several blank cells between them as shown below. For example:

```
1   Text
    Text
    Text
2   Text
    Text
    Text
3   Text
    Text
```

I need to insert a blank row just above each of the numbers in column A.

Can anyone help me to set up an excel macro to insert a blank row just above the cell containing a number in column A.

Comment: SRJ, to confirm, do you want to insert a row there or just a cell and shift column A down?

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, there is a little ambiguity in your description but this is what I've come up with to *exactly* conform to the requirements specified.

```
Dim r As Long
For r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Cells(r, 1).Value) And CBool(Len(Cells(r, 1).Value)) Then _
        Rows(r).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
Next r
```